# SPFx Web Part Title using No Javascript Framework

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have been searching all over for any solution to adding a web part title just like the OOTB web parts for my custom SPFx web part.

The only solutions I have been able to find are only ones that use React Framework. I am not using React, I am using the 'No Javascript Framework' option.

Is there a way to achieve this using the 'No Javascript Framework'?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is your render view, you could render the data as your format, while it would be more complex as you need code all render logic by yourself, there would be controls have implemented this render logic if you use React.

Comment: I see, just seeing if there was a predefined way to do this before I try to recreate it.

Comment: No, either  
@pnp/spfx-controls-react or office fabric will depends on react, while you would try proper jQuery libraries if any.